# Alamofire 4.0.0 erorr in Xcode 8 Beta 6

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire, swift3, xcode8-beta6

i'm using Xcode 8 beta 6 with swift 3 and i installing alamofire 4.0.0 beta 1 from cocoapods with using this code

```
 pod 'Alamofire',
  :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git',
  :branch => 'swift3'
```

after installing, i open xcworkspace file but its erorr and Xcode ask for converting code from swift 2.2 to 3. I also set platform target to ios 9.0 but it's still not works. anyone can help? thanks

Comment: you should post that edit as a regular answer below. An answer is allowed to be your own.

Comment: ahh ok... thanks for your info @pedrouan